# phpMyAdmin - #1130 - Host 'SERVER' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: phpmyadmin, wampserver, mysql-error-1130

I run WAMPServer on a `Windows server 2012 r2`, I want to run a database on it using phpMyAdmin, everything is working but when I try to login from the Windows server I get this error:

is the error that I see.

[image]

I get the same error when I try to login from a other computer.

There are allot of people having this problem so I searched all over the internet but all I can find are query's that can fix this problem.. But I can't login so I can't do anything with those query's.

I hope someone can fix this problem for me, I would really appreciate it!

The two errors I get on the picture:

```
#1130 - Host 'SERVER' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1130): Host 'SERVER' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WAMPServer is configired to be a single user developer tool. Therefore the security is configured to protect the beginner.

Therefore:

1. The phpMyAdmin alias is configured to only accept connections from the PC running WAMPServer.
2. As in any sensibe default config of MYSQL the `root` and any other
   pre-configured MYSQL user accounts are also configured to only be
   accessible from the PC running MYSQL.

So to allow you to run phpMyAdmin from another host (PC) you need to amend the Alias configuration for phpMyAdmin.

So edit `\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf` (***NOTE*** your version may be different) and amend the `Require` setting to allow access from specific, or all the Ip Addresses in yor subnet.

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "D:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.7.0/"

<Directory "D:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.7.0/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
  <ifDefine APACHE24>
        Require local

        ## Add access allowed from your subnet
        Require ip 192.168.1

    </ifDefine>
    <ifDefine !APACHE24>
        Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
    </ifDefine>

# To import big file you can increase values
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

Now you should be able to run `phpMyAdmin` from another PC

You must now create a user within MYSQL that is allowed to access the database(s) that that user requires access to from whichever remote IP Addresses that user is allowed to access the database from. You should go to the Server and using phpMyAdmin, login as `root` from there, remember `root` can only login from the PC running MYSQL.

I suggest you **do not** amend the access rights of `root` but instead create a new user and give whatever access that user is allowed to which ever databases that user is allowed to access.

For example,

```
CREATE USER 'raul'@'192.168.1.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass' PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER;
```

Will allow you to login from any of the ip addresses in the `192.168.1` subnet. *Amend this to fit your actual situation.*

And then allow that user access to the databases he will require.

```
GRANT ALL ON test.* TO 'raul'@'localhost';
```

This is all possible using point and click via `phpMyAdmin`

Comment: Well I would love to execute those query's, but I can't login that is the whole problem. Thanks for the long answer tho!

Comment: You missed the point. You can login if you do so by going to the Server PC and doing this

Comment: None of the DEFAULT user accounts in MYSQL will allow you to connect from a remote PC. Its a security mechanism to protect beginners and any new install of MYSQL from getting hacked

Comment: Sorry but I cannot login from either the localhost or any other computer. The login is blocked.

Comment: From the server console try launching phpmydmin using `localhost/phpmyadmin`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by going to `wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf` and made it like this:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "F:/SERVER/apps/phpmyadmin4.9.2/"

<Directory "F:/SERVER/apps/phpmyadmin4.9.2/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
  <ifDefine APACHE24>
        Require local
        Require ip 192.168.1
        Require ip 192.168.2
        Require ip 127.0.0.1
    </ifDefine>
    <ifDefine !APACHE24>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
    </ifDefine>

# To import big file you can increase values
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

AND hosts from `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and added

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1
::1 localhost
```

Also needed to go to `F:\SERVER\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.28\my.ini` and add or uncommment

```
[wampmysqld64]
skip-grant-tables
```

In order to do the steps above with grant tables as is not possible to log in to mysql if you don't have the option `skip-grant-tables` and execute the sql from @RiggsFolly