# Accessing PHPMYADMIN remotely

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

I am able to access my wamp servers local host on a remote computer but still not able to access the PHPMYADMIN that is accompanied with this. I get a forbidden message that says I do not have permission to access. Any ideas on why I am able to access the local host information page but not the phpmyadmin page? Here are screenshots of the local host page and when I try to access the phpmyadmin page from a remote computer. [image: ][1]]

[image]

I am using the ip address of the host computer to access the site.

Comment: Do I need to install phpmyadmin on every computer that wants to access the database? I was under the assumption that if its installed on the host computer it can be accessed on any other computer without having to install it again.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157454/phpmyadmin-1130-host-server-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-serve/43169519#43169519

Comment: But be careful. Allowing external access via phpMyAdmin also allows remote users to delete databases unless you create user accounts for all the remote users with limited privilages